# upper bound of combination sum

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I try to find the upper bound and lower bound of the following sum:
$$2^{f(k)}\leq \sum_{i=0}^k{n\choose i}\leq 2^{g(k)}$$ 
where $k\leq n$. I got the lower bound is $2^{k}$, but I got stuck with the upper bound, a trivial upper bound is $2^n$. but can we do better?

Comment: This problem is essentially equivalent to finding accurate approximations for the error function, by the CLT.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio would you mind sharing some materials related to this?

Comment: $2^{-n}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{n}{i}$ is the probability that a binomial random variable takes a value $\leq k$. The central limit theorem gives that the binomial distribution approaches the normal distribution for large values of $n$, hence the problem boils down to approximating $$\int_{-\infty}^{T} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt.$$ That can be efficiently done through continued fractions or classical probabilistic inequalities. Have a look at this MO thread, too: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1283/erfc-lower-bound/133829#133829

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks alot